# Is there a way to create shorter names for HTML attributes?

Tags: html

Inside a wysiwyg editor, I have to code a lot of non-editable divs. This following method works :
`<div contenteditable="false"> Non editable content here </div>`

But "contenteditable" is quite a long word and i'd like to shorten it. Is there a way to define something at the top of the html file like "define ce = contenteditable" and then using it like that `<div ce="false">...</div>` ? I know that example doesn't work, but is there another, similar way ?

Comment: More on-topic to the question at hand: since you haven't mentioned anything regarding it, are JavaScript-based solutions acceptable? HTML doesn't have anything resembling variables, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to alias the html element attributes.

However, the div element is not editable by default. Therefore it should not be necessary to set `contenteditable="false"` on any div. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

If you are finding that this is necessary to prevent the rendered content from being edited, then that may be an effect of the wysiwyg editor you are using.